# Add default navigation bar on viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button and when pressed it presents a new viewController, like a pop up window.

```
- (IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
    PopUpObj = [[PopUpViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:PopUpObj animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The View appears as it should but it has no nav bar with back button.

In the PopUpViewController I create a nav bar like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
[navbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[self.view addSubview:navbar];

UIBarButtonItem* myBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:nil
                                 action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton;

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The nav bar appears but the back button item doesn't appear at all. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `backBarButtonItem` is displayed when you push another viewController onto the navigation stack.  Think of it as the button that will be used to get back to your PopUpViewController, not the button displayed whilst showing your PopUpViewController.  Change `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Have you tried using pushViewController rather than presentViewController to load the popup view controller?

Comment: Yes then it works, but I want the viewcontroller to slide up from the bottom, not from the left. Can I somehow change the segue style of the pushViewController?

Comment: So the problem is that your PopUpViewController doesn't know it's in a NavController.  You could try wrapping it in a NavController and presenting that.